# ASIHTTPRequest setDownloadDestinationPath doesn't write file

Tags: iphone, asihttprequest

Consider the following code:

```
    ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.168.2.71:3000/ios_file?filename=complaint&folder=encounters&id=3"]];
NSString *mediaPath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];
mediaPath = [mediaPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"complaint.MOV"];
[request setDownloadDestinationPath:mediaPath];
[request startSynchronous];
NSLog(@"Got the file!");
NSURL *theURL = [NSURL URLWithString:mediaPath];

NSLog(@"Time to Play File!");
NSLog(@"Filename is %@", [theURL absoluteString]);

BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[theURL absoluteString]];

if (fileExists) {
    NSLog(@"THE FILE EXISTS ZOMG");
}

// Create file manager
NSError *error;
NSFileManager *fileMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

// Point to Document directory
NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];

// Write out the contents of home directory to console
NSLog(@"Documents directory: %@", [fileMgr contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory error:&error]);
```

Returns the following:

```
2011-03-30 18:29:46.107 VideoCapture[158:707] Get recording from server
2011-03-30 18:29:46.976 VideoCapture[158:707] Got the file!
2011-03-30 18:29:46.978 VideoCapture[158:707] Time to Play File!
2011-03-30 18:29:46.980 VideoCapture[158:707] Filename is /var/mobile/Applications/AE4B3091-3726-4FAE-B861-C4AE3616E743/Documents/complaint.MOV
2011-03-30 18:29:46.986 VideoCapture[158:707] Documents directory: (null)
```

Going to the URL in question sends me a quicktime movie (I'm using Ruby's send_data File.read("#{file_path}.MOV"), :disposition => 'inline', :type => "video/quicktime").

As you can see, there are no files in the directory! Help!

Comment: Also just to note, I tried this with a direct file from the server (http://192.168.2.71:3000/fake_recordings/encounters/2/complaint.MOV) without the need for a controller and this had the same issue. Even though I could open the file correctly using my web browser in both instances.

Comment: Try to add the failure callback and see if it get called?

Comment: Valid point, I did that and recieved this:

2011-03-30 19:01:01.957 VideoCapture[246:707] Error: Failed to move file from '/private/var/mobile/Applications/AE4B3091-3726-4FAE-B861-C4AE3616E743/tmp/6A81D988-74EF-4085-AB1F-8EFF11008736-246-0000000F08A0C88D' to '/var/mobile/Applications/AE4B3091-3726-4FAE-B861-C4AE3616E743/Documents/complaint.MOV'

Comment: Yeah. Try use the path suggested by Matthew's method instead. That's how I get my path too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Under iOS `NSHomeDirectory()` and the appended path isn't the proper way to get to the Document directory and may be what's hanging you up. Instead use something along these lines:

```
NSString *documentDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
NSString *mediaPath = [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"complaint.MOV"];
```

Comment: Tried this solution, unfortunately still unable to download the file.

2011-03-31 11:19:19.670 VideoCapture[1047:707] Filename is /var/mobile/Applications/AE4B3091-3726-4FAE-B861-C4AE3616E743/Documents/complaint.MOV
2011-03-31 11:19:19.671 VideoCapture[1047:707] Error: Failed to move file from '/private/var/mobile/Applications/AE4B3091-3726-4FAE-B861-C4AE3616E743/tmp/EBA8412C-16AE-4B57-ACC6-A5C74BD0334E-1047-000000A15A2CEE06' to '/var/mobile/Applications/AE4B3091-3726-4FAE-B861-C4AE3616E743/Documents/complaint.MOV'
2011-03-31 11:19:19.679 VideoCapture[1047:707] Documents directory: (null)

Comment: @user164458 Is this on the device or in the simulator? That's definitely an invalid path in the simulator, and I don't think it's right ont he device, either.

Answer (score 1):

I had the similar problem. Realized that it happens when you set the delegate (ASIHTTPRequestDelegate) for the request to be self. If you avoid this, it can write the file.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are downloading the document with a standard ASIHTTPRequest (i.e. not receiving the bytes in an NSData object and handling it manually) the best way to resolve this issue is as follows:

1) Implement the ASIHTTPRequestDelegate methods
2) In the requestFinished method you can move the file manually using the NSFileManager
3) Play the movie from the new modified path

Below is a verbose example of how to achieve this. Modify as needed for more tight simplified code.

```
// create NSFileManager
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

// grab the current request object's download path, minus the file extension
NSString *directoryPath = [[request downloadDestinationPath] stringByDeletingPathExtension];

// append the desired file extension
NSString *destintionPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.mov", directoryPath];

// move the file
[fileManager moveItemAtPath:[request downloadDestinationPath] toPath:destintionPath error:nil];
```

I was able to download a QuickTime movie using this code without error. By default it will download to the downloadDestinationPath, which in this case will be in GUID.html format. Then we rename it to GUID.mov and then send off for playing in the MPMoviePlayer.